# Is it safe to allow a user to upload a custom font to a server to be displayed to other users?

Tags: css, web-applications

I recently started to learn web development and for a feature of a project I was working on I was wondering. Is it safe to allow a user to upload fonts to the server for it to be served to the rest of the users or does it involve a security risk?

Comment: Adding it would always open the door to a possible zero-day exploit with fonts, why do you want to do this?